# function generates list of dictionaires

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples

```
[('color','blue'),('number',3),('place','usa'),('color','yellow'),('place','canada')...]
```

I wanted to build a function that would return me a list of dictionaires

```
[{'color':blue, 'number':3, 'place':'usa'}, {'color':yellow, 'number':'', 'place':'camada'},...]
```

The function would have to create a new dictionaire everytime it found one of the keys which already have an asigned value

In the above example, as it iterates by the list of tuples, at the first tuple it would create an empty dictionaire with the keys and and empty value ('') -the keys are always the same- and update the values based on the tuple keys. Then when it reaches a tupple for which the key already has an assigned value ('color','yellow') it would have to create another dictionaire and update the value of color to yellow and so on...

the function then would return a list of the dictionaires...

I can do it for one dictionaire, but do not know how to make it create a new one and how to store them...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what output you're after, but maybe something like

```
def tups_to_dicts(kv_pairs):
    # split into dictionaries
    ds = []
    for key, val in kv_pairs:
        if not ds or key in ds[-1]:
            ds.append({})
        ds[-1][key] = val
    # pad the empty values
    all_seen_keys = set().union(*ds)
    ds = [{key: d.get(key, '') for key in all_seen_keys} for d in ds]
    return ds
```

would get you close?  It produces

```
>>> data = [('color','blue'),('number',3),('place','usa'),('color','yellow'),('place','canada'), ('color', 'orange'), ('sport', 'hockey')]
>>> dd = tups_to_dicts(data)
>>> for d in dd:
...     print d
...     
{'color': 'blue', 'sport': '', 'place': 'usa', 'number': 3}
{'color': 'yellow', 'sport': '', 'place': 'canada', 'number': ''}
{'color': 'orange', 'sport': 'hockey', 'place': '', 'number': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `list comprehensions`

```
given = [('color', 'blue'), ('number', 3), ('place', 'usa'),
         ('color', 'yellow'), ('number', 3), ('place', 'canada')]

print [dict(given[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(given) - 2, 3)]
```

Output

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'place': 'usa', 'number': 3},
 {'color': 'yellow', 'place': 'canada', 'number': 3}]
```

Note - You must have *all* value-tuples for this to work i.e. you can't have only `color` & `number` & skip `place` in some seqquence. The order & the grouping is important here.